# css file is not linked to the rest of the website's pages

Tags: css

i added a new file for the CSS in VS code and wrote all the styles codes and wrote the link element in each page in the website but the CSS styles are not applied to the website

i was trying to apply a style for all pages and i was expecting it work normally

---

```
body {
    background-color:#b3e6ee
}
hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: grey;
  border-width: 7px;
  width: 6%;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
}
h1 {
    color: #66BFBF;
}
h3 {
    color: #66BFBF;
}
here are the css file
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> magzwebsite </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
```

and here is the index.html file

Comment: You forgot a semicolon on line 2

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolon at the end of the first parameter in the *body* selector.

```css
body {
    background-color: #b3e6ee;
}
```

This should fix it.